# is a variable with a private access modifier .. not visible to the new object created using that class definition?

Tags: java

I wanted to know whether a private access modifier before a variable in a class definition  makes it inaccessible to the object created?

Simply putt, are the values of private attribute variables loaded in the heap memory when a new object is created using that class?

For example: suppose I create a class (lets call it *CLASS1*) which has an attribute variable called *private int p1=10;* and i make a method `public void Updatep1(int a){
p1=a;}`

Now if I create an object `CLASS1 object1=new CLASS1`
in the main method and then try to print the value of p1, I get an error saying that it is inaccessible as it's a non-static variable.. and hence inaccessible!

Please look at the following example:

```
public class DateThree {

  private int day;
  private int month;
  private int year;

  public void setDay(int d) {
    day = d;
  }

  public int getDay() {
    return day;
  }

  public void setMonth(int m) {
    month = m;
  }

  public int getMonth() {
          return month;
  }

  public void setYear(int y) {
    year = y;
  }

  public int getYear() {
    return year;
  }

  public int calcDaysInMonth() {

    switch(month) {
    case 1:
    case 3:
    case 5:
    case 7:
    case 8:
    case 10:
    case 12:
      return 31;
    case 2:
      return 28;
    case 4:
    case 6:
    case 9:
    case 11:
      return 30;
    default:
      System.out.println("Invalid month.");
      return 0;
    }
  }
```

If I call the above class from another class..

```
 public class DateThreeTest {

  public static void main(String args[]) {

    DateThree d = new DateThree();
    int days = d.calcDaysInMonth();
    System.out.println("Days in Month:" + days);
  }
 }
```

But as per theory, this should not work, as *month* is private and hence inaccessible to the new object, and hence the *d.CalcDaysInMonth* should give an error as it requires a private method *month* to function, which is not there in the new file and is neither accessible to the new method, yet it does not give an error, it works!

So my question is: from where does the object in the DateThreeTest (namely `d`) get the month variable's value?

Comment: Read up on [Declaring Member Variables](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/variables.html)

Answer (score 1):

You are missing something. :)

In Object Oriented programming, a data member

- represents a property of an objet  (intent/concept/modelling interest)
- and it is a varialbe accesible in all methods of the objet (this is more of a way of programming, sharing variables between methods)

Data members, whatever visibility modifier they have, are in the scope of the objet, they live as long as an objet lives. `private` data members are accessible from within all methods of the class, but not from any where else.

As soon as you instanciate an object in java, his fields are initialized, indeed, instanciation is barely just that.

When, in your example, you call `d.calcDaysInMonth()`, it will use d's data members, the variable month refer to the attribute you declared at the beginning of DateThree class :

```
 private int month;
```

Does that make more sense ?

Please, note that all of the above does not apply to static fields but to non- static fields (normal if you want).

Good luck in OOP, but read more about it.

Regards, 
 stéphane

Comment: @Snicolas--- no.. that confuses me... well i get the concept that the data member private {int month is} accessible only  to it's class methods and other variables within the class.. but when we create an object of that class... it becomes inaccessible .. right???.. that's the whole point of making a data member private? is it not??

Comment: When you haev private data members inside an object, these fields are not accesible from within methods of other classes. Only what is public is accessible from within those methods. You can't test that with only one class. Here is a good tutorial/explanation : http://www.programmingvideotutorials.com/java/java-access-levels